# loading a txt or xls to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to load a txt file that holds all the information I want to load to the JTable but I don't know how to do so.
I looked for a solution but couldn't really find one. PLEASE HELP!
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class Table2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, TableModelListener{


//String[] column = {"Name","Age","Gender"};
Object[][] data = {{"John","20","Male"}};
JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, new Object[]{"Name", "Age","Gender"})){

        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int col){ //gives a pattern to the table cells.
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, col);

        if(data % 2 == 0){
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        else{
            c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
        return c;
    }

};

//JTable table = new JTable(data,column);

public Table2(){

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300,200));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollpane);

    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this); //Adds the model listener to the table. (checks if any changes are made and activated on table changed method.)
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Table2 table = new Table2();
    table.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    table.setVisible(true);
    table.setSize(400,300);
    table.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    table.setResizable(false);
    table.setTitle("Table Prictice on JFrame");
    //table.pack();

    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    table.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(table);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"", "", ""});
    System.out.println("Action Performed!");
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Table change detected by tableChange method!");
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    System.out.println("---TEST LINE---");

    try {

        saveTable();
    }

    catch (Exception e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public void saveTable()throws Exception
{
  BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Table Data.txt")); //use Excel extension once finished. (txt for now)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < table.getColumnCount() ; i++)
  {
    bfw.write(table.getColumnName(i));
    bfw.write("\t");
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
    bfw.newLine();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < table.getColumnCount();j++)
    {
      bfw.write((String)(table.getValueAt(i,j)));
      bfw.write("\t");;
    }
  }
  bfw.close();
}

}
```

Basically I want to load the txt file each time I relaunch the program so that all of the information is stored.

Answer (score 1):

The code to load the data will be the opposite of your code to write the data:

1. Read a line of data from your file
2. Use the `String.split(...)` to create an array of values for each colum
3. Use the `DefaultTableModel.addRow(...)` method to add the Array to the TableModel
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until all the data has been read and the add the TableModel to the JTable using the `JTable.setModel(...)` method.